# Oracle 19c and ONS and FAN Events

Tags: oracle

I am working on learning more about Oracle Transparent Application continuity and FAN events.  I noticed on my test 2 node 19.21 Oracle RAC that I get this error when I type the following onsctl error.  Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
[oracle@rac1 ~]$ onsctl debug
[2023-12-08T17:17:41-06:00] [ons] [ERROR:1] [] [ons-local] ONS: (warning) LocalPort directive is missing
[2023-12-08T17:17:41-06:00] [ons] [ERROR:1] [] [ons-local] ONS: (warning) RemotePort directive is missing
[2023-12-08T17:17:41-06:00] [ons] [ERROR:1] [] [ons-local] ONS: LocalPort directive is missing
[2023-12-08T17:17:41-06:00] [ons] [ERROR:1] [] [ons-local] ONS: RemotePort directive is missing
```

ONS is up and running and this is my configuration files but I am perplexed as to why this i happening.  Any way to figure out why?

```
usesharedinstall=true
allowgroup=true
localport=6100          # line added by Agent
remoteport=6200         # line added by Agent
nodes=rac1:6200,rac2:6200               # line added by Agent
walletfile=/u01/app/oracle/crsdata/rac1/onswallet/              # line added by Agent
allowunsecuresubscriber=yes             # line added by Agent
allowpublish=::ffff:10.0.10.31,10.0.10.31,::ffff:10.0.10.201,10.0.10.201                # line added by Agent
```

this looks right...

```
[oracle@rac1 ~]$ srvctl config nodeapps -s
ONS exists: Local port 6100, remote port 6200, EM port 2016, Uses SSL true
ONS is enabled
ONS is individually enabled on nodes:
ONS is individually disabled on nodes:
```

It shows it listening

```
[oracle@rac1 ~]$ netstat -na | grep 6200
tcp6       0      0 :::6200                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 10.0.10.31:6200         10.0.10.201:38508       ESTABLISHED
[oracle@rac1 ~]$ netstat -na | grep 6200
tcp6       0      0 :::6200                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 10.0.10.31:6200         10.0.10.201:38508       ESTABLISHED
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

try running the onsctl commands as the GRID user

Comment: Please add a link to the documentation, and include pertinent details about how this resolves the issue.